# Scanf syntax - %6d and %-6d and %0d

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

What are the differences between using `scanf` with the following format specifiers, when the input being scanned is `123456` versus when it's `123`:

- `%6d`
- `%-6d`
- `%0d`

What are the differences in the output?

Comment: scanf does not do output. Did you mean printf?

Comment: well if i use it with scanf will it cut only the first 6 digits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up just trying it with GCC 4.3.4, and got the following:

- `%6d`: Works fine; only reads 6 characters (so if you try to read `123456789` it will only read `123456`)
- `%-6d`: Emits the warning:

  ```
  warning: unknown conversion type character '-' in format
  ```

  Doesn't read anything, and the int being written to is unmodified
- `%0d`: Emits the warning:

  ```
  warning: zero width in scanf format
  ```

  Reads as though there were no width in the format specifier (`%d`)

I haven't checked the spec to see if those results are mandated or just how GCC handles it (**EDIT**: [AndreyT found it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783722/scanf-syntax-6d-and-6d-and-0d/4783862#4783862))

Answer (score 6):

The `%-6d` is an invalid format specifier. There are no format specifiers with `-` in them in `scanf`.

In `%6d` the `6` part is called *maximum field width*. It works with all format specifiers (not only with `d`) and specifies the maximum number of characters to read before any format-specific conversion is performed. For example, if input sequence is `1234567`, then `%3d` will read and convert `123` and `%6d` will read and convert `123456`.

The `%0d` is an invalid format specifier. Maximum field width in `scanf` must be a non-zero integer (see 7.19.6.2/3 in the language specification).

So, that leaves us with `%6d` as the only meaningful format specifier among the three you provided. Under these circumstances the question about differences in output (in results?) makes little sense.

**EDIT:** One can probably argue that in `%-6d` the `-6` part is the maximum field width, which satisfies the standard requirement of being *non-zero decimal integer*. However, in C language terminology a *decimal integer* as a lexical element is a sequence of digits and digits only. It is not allowed to include a sign. I.e. neither `-6` nor `+6` are decimal integers. Every time you use `-6` or `+6` as integers in your program it is actually unary `-` and `+` operator lexeme followed by decimal integer lexeme. So, since the specification of `scanf` requires a *non-zero decimal integer* as maximum field width, it must be a sign-less integer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think will happen: %6d will get you the first 6 digits of the number, %-6d will probably not work as you expect, since - is more of an output alignment specifier. %0d would mean you want only 0 characters, which would probably not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Both `%-6d` and `%0d` are **invalid** conversion specifications for `scanf`, so the behavior for those cases will be **undefined**.  See the language [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), § 7.19.6.2, ¶ 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume, like Arkadiy, that you really meant printf-style formatting, since you refer to "output".  I'll also assume that you're using C (as the tag suggests).

If you run:

```
printf("%6d %-6d %0d", num1, num2);
```

...you'll end up with compiler errors (or, worse still, runtime bugs), as you haven't supplied enough arguments for three formats.

I've a feeling that that's not what you were asking, though.  Let's assume that you actually run:

```
// (I've added some extra stuff to show how the formatting works.)
printf("'%6d'/'%-6d'/'%0d'", num2, num2, num2);
```

...you'll get:

```
'   123'/'123   '/'123'
```

Normally, if the field width (6 in this case) is wide enough, numbers are right-aligned, space-padded.  If you put a '-' before the field width, they will be right-aligned, space-padded.

The subtlety here is in the "%0d" format.  You might think you're specifying a zero-width field...and you'd be wrong.  The first thing after the '%' is an option flag, and '0' is a valid flag.  It means, "If the field width is wider than the content, left-pad with zeroes."  In this case, you haven't supplied a field width (the '0' is a flag, remember?), so the '0' flag has no effect: the field will be as wide as the content requires.

There's an even worse subtlety, though.  If you specified "%-06d", you'd get right-padding with zeroes, right?  Um, no.  The '-' flag overrides the '0' flag, whichever order they're supplied.  You'd get '123   '.